# Uniform Convergence of a sequence so that $lim_{n\to\infty} { A_{n+1}\over A_n} = L$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that {${A_n}$}$_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of numbers so that 
$lim_{n\to\infty} { A_{n+1}\over A_n} = L$
and $0 < L < 1$. Show that the sequence of functions
￼$g_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n A_k {sin(kx)\over 2^k}$ converges uniformly on any interval $[a,b]$.

I know I may need to use that fact that $sin(x)\leq1$ for all x.

Comment: Have you seen the Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: Yes I have, but that test was not introduced in this class. Thus, I am unable to use it. That is how I originally did this proof but my teacher wouldn't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n} = L$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $\displaystyle \left|\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}\right| < \frac{3L}{2}$ for all $n \ge N$. Thus $$|A_{n+1}| = \left|\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}\right|\cdot \left|\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}\right|\cdots \left|\frac{A_2}{A_1}\right| \cdot |A_1| < \left(\frac{3L}{2}\right)^n |A_1|$$ for all $n \ge N$. Now $$|g_{n+1}(x) - g_n(x)| = \left|A_{n+1}\frac{\sin[(n+1)x]}{2^{n+1}}\right| \le \frac{|A_{n+1}|}{2^{n+1}} < \left(\frac{3L}{4}\right)^n \frac{|A_1|}{2}$$

whenever $n \ge N$ and $x \in \Bbb R$. Thus, for all $n \ge m \ge N$ and $x \in \Bbb R$,

$$|g_n(x) - g_m(x)| \le \sum_{k = m}^{n-1} |g_{k+1}(x) - g_k(x)| \le \sum_{k = m}^\infty |g_{k+1}(x) - g_k(x)| \le \left(\frac{3L}{4}\right)^m \frac{|A_1|}{1 - \frac{3L}{4}}.$$

Since the last expression tends to $0$ as $m \to \infty$, the result follows by the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence.